# how to capture packets sent by XDP user space program

Tags: bpf, ebpf, xdp-bpf

Say I have XDP kernel and user programs. Kernel code examines ingress packets and "forwards" them to XDP user space program. XDP user space program then does some processing and sends packets out (could be same NIC or other one). 
For controlling reasons we want to examine the *outgoing* packets sent by XDP user space code. Our first idea was using tc and insert BPF code to egress part, clearly didn't work.

Any idea?

EDIT1: egress program:

```c
SEC("tx")
int track_tx(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
    __u64 t2 = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
    bpf_custom_printk("\n__________send length %d\n", data_end-data); 
    return TC_ACT_OK;
}
```

run:
`sudo tc filter add dev ens13 egress bpf da obj layercoop.o sec tx`

EDIT2: Code 
USer: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/xdpsock_user.c

Kernel (not interesting): https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/xdpsock_kern.c

I want to forward incoming packets, so run it with `make -j 4; sudo ./xdpsock -i ens13 -l`

Comment: What do you mean by “XDP user space program”? Is this a normal user space programs that retrieves your packets from an AF_XDP socket, or something else?

Comment: Can you show exactly how you "insert[ed] BPF code to egress part"? It would help if you could include example userspace (XDP) and kernel space programs (tc)...

Comment: @Qeole Yes the program runs in user land and eats packet using AF_XDP socket. Like this : https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/xdpsock_user.c

Comment: @pchaigno `sudo tc filter add dev ens13 egress bpf da obj layercoop.o sec tx`. Code see my post.

Comment: I think your packets won't hit the tc egress interface indeed (it would ruin the performance that AF_XDP provides). I'm not sure there are other hooks this low in the stack to observe your packets, though :/. Since you're sending the packets from your user space app, can't you just do monitoring there? Or if you want to see if packets are actually sent, have a look at NIC statistics or at what the machine on the other end of the link receives?

Comment: @Qeole yeah we need that low level monitoring/intercept-ing, and on the sender-machine. If it is impossible with kernel bpf we may consider using [hardware ebpf](https://www.netronome.com/m/documents/viljoen-xdpoffload-talk_2.pdf)

Comment: Yeah I thought about it (I worked on BPF offload until recently). Although you can offload BPF programs to the Netronome SmartNICs, capture packets and send them through the perf ring buffer, you should be aware that you cannot attach programs on the egress path (TC on egress not supported by hardware, XDP on egress does not exist in kernel as of this writing).

Comment: Ah and also the SmartNICs have no support for AF_XDP at the moment.

Comment: @Qeole hm what can it do now? I just need to intercept the packets and manipulate them (drop, read/write packet data, ...)

Comment: You can do all that with programs attached to either TC or XDP on the ingress path, and hardware offload is available for both :). Your specific requirement of “monitoring packets once they get out of the AF_XDP TX ring” is more difficult to address, but it doesn't mean you cannot do regular packet processing without it.